# Equally spaced divs same space between divs and on the left and right off the screen - CSS

Tags: css, html, space

I have three divs with fixed width: 400px inside a container of with width: 100%

So let's say that we are on a 1920px screen.

The remaining space is 1920 - (400*3) = 720. So I want this available space to divide it by 4 and distribute it evenly. So the first div has to have on the left 180px, the space between the first div and the second to be 180px ,the space between the second and third div to be 180px and the space between the third div with the end of the screen to be 180px again.

The spaces between the divs and the screens should change depending the size of the screen.

Is it possible to do it with css?

**Sample:**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Display:flex is made for this :) .
on container use :

```
display:flex;
justify-content:space-around;
```

on child, just set a width, % or static value.

There's a work around with text-align:justify and display:inline-block; and pseudos if you need

test : here http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qcFBt/ *`padding inside`*

text-align version : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/piCtm/

Comment: Using @GCyrillus' solution does cause one issue if you want the 400px-wide elements to maintain their width: they shrink when the screen size is too small. To ensure they're always 400px wide (and prompt a scrollbar when the screen is too narrow), use `min-width: 400px`. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fDjZU/15/)

Comment: you need to add some padding to swallow the gap in middle, check it here http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qcFBt/

Comment: Thanks a lot! As far I know flex is not supported by IE9. I don't care below IE9. Is there any other way or I have to do it with js for ie only ?

Comment: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/piCtm/ this the text-align version, it should work in IE9 nojs , code commented